# Javascript MVC + listening and dispatching events with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning javascript and have a question about listening and dispatching events with jQuery.

In my Model, I have a function that triggers a change event:

```
Model.prototype.setCurrentID = function(currentID) {
    this.currentID = currentID;
    $('body').trigger('change');
}
```

The trigger event requires an element, so I bound it to the 'body'.  Is this good practice or bad practice?

In AS3, which I'm more familiar, I would simply dispatch a global event from the model, passing in a const value, listening for this event with an instance of the Model:

```
var model:Model = new Model();
model.addEventListener(CONST_VALUE, handlerFunction);
```

In jQuery, within my View object, I need to attach an element to the listener as well, so I bound it to the 'body' once again:

```
var View = function(model, controller) {
    var model;
    var controller;
    this.model = model;
    this.controller = controller;

    $('body').change(function(evt) { updateSomething(evt); });

    function updateSomething(evt){console.log('updating...')};
}
```

It's working, but I'm interested in your take on the subject.

Comment: It looks like you have an extra right-brace "}" in $('body').change(function(evt) { updateSomething(evt); });
        function updateSomething(evt){console.log('updating...')}
extra---> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a private dispatcher, something that isn't exposed to the public.
For instance, your logic may fail if the user or a plugin unbinds all the events on the body(your dispatcher) :

```
$('body').unbind();
```

This can be avoided by creating a dom node and not expose it to the end user (do not append it to the dom) :

```
var dispatcher = $('<div />');

Model.prototype.setCurrentID = function(currentID) {
    this.currentID = currentID;
    dispatcher.trigger('change');
}

var View = function(model, controller) {
    this.model = model;
    this.controller = controller;

    dispatcher.bind('change',function(evt) { updateSomething(evt); });
    function updateSomething(evt){console.log('updating...')}
}
```

Another good thing to have in mind when developing event-programming app with jQuery is that jQuery allows you to bind/trigger custom events and also allows you [to namespace your events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events). This way you can control more efficiently the event binding and triggering :

```
Model.prototype.setCurrentID = function(currentID) {
    this.currentID = currentID;
    dispatcher.trigger('modelIdChange.' + this.currentID);
}
Model.prototype.destroy = function() {
    // unbind all the event handlers for this particular model
    dispatcher.unbind('.'+this.currentID);
}

var View = function(model, controller) {
    /*...*/

    // this will be triggered for all the changes
    dispatcher.bind('modelIdChange',function(evt) { updateSomething(evt); });

    // this will be triggered only for the model with the id "id1"
    dispatcher.bind('modelIdChange.id1',function(evt) { updateSomething(evt); });

    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Excellent!  This is was very very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I'd go a step further and create custom global events. With jQuery you can trigger a global custom event like so:

```
$.event.trigger('change');
```

Any element can subscribe to that event:

```
$('#myDiv').bind('change', function() {
  console.log($(this));
});
```

The `this` keyword in the event handler is the DOM element which subscribed to the triggered event.

Answer (score 0):

My objections are:

- I wouldn't bind events that have the same name as broswer events, there might be interferences.
- Your code works if you have one model, but if you have 2 or more, you'd want to separate them, and not bind/trigger both on the same element.

How about:

```
Model.prototype.bind = function(event, func) {
    if (!this._element) this._element = $('<div>');
    this._element.bind(this.name+'_'+event, $.proxy(func, this));
    return this;
};
Model.prototype.trigger = function(event) {
    if (!this._element) this._element = $('<div>');
    this._element.trigger(this.name+'_'+event);
    return this;
};
```

This way you solve both. Note I'm appending `this.name+'_'` to event names (which assume each model has some sort of name, and makes sure events won't match with browser events), but you can also drop the the prefix.

I'm also using [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) in bind so that the `this` in the event handler refers to the model.

```
var View = function(model, controller) {
    ....
    model.bind('change', function() {...});
}
```